# PHP: Extract elements from array A at current key and push to array B

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building my first web app. I'm using the openweathermap API. Right now I'm trying to create a 5 day forecast. I want to get the current day from my array and push it plus the next 4 days to a new array. I'm stuck pushing 'today' to my new array 5 times. I've tried pushing next($day_name) as well. Here's the code.

```
                $day_name = array(
                1=>'Monday',
                2=>'Tuesday',
                3=>'Wednesday',
                4=>'Thursday',
                5=>'Friday',
                6=>'Saturday',
                7=>'Sunday');
                $day_start = date('N');
                foreach ( $day_name as $dk => $dv )
                {
                  if( $dk == $day_start and current($day_name))
                  {
                    $five_days = array();
                    while(count($five_days) !== 5)
                    {
                          array_push($five_days, $dv);
                    }
                    break;
                  }

                }
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($five_days);
                echo '</pre>';
```

This prints:

```
Array(
[0] => Sunday
[1] => Sunday
[2] => Sunday
[3] => Sunday
[4] => Sunday
)
```

Welcome any answers using the original script as I may need to use something similar in the future.

Comment: Are you trying to get the next 5 days?

Comment: Yes, corrected the title. I want to get the current day plus the next four days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get today and next four days, One option is using `DatePeriod`

```
$five_days   = [];
$period = new DatePeriod (
    new DateTime(), 
    new DateInterval('P1D'), 
    4
);

foreach ($period as $day)
{
    $five_days[] = $day->format('l');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($five_days);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sunday
    [1] => Monday
    [2] => Tuesday
    [3] => Wednesday
    [4] => Thursday
)
```